# How to correctly use php_cli in an *.sh script?

Tags: php, shell

From a test_script.sh:

```
php_cli -f somefile.php
```

gives an error: "Could not open input file: somefile.php"

but

```
php_cli -f somefile.php some_random_string
```

runs ok.

Directly from the shell:

```
php_cli -f somefile.php
```

doesn't give an error.

Why do I have to pass an additional string(argument?) in test_script.sh to php_cli for it to execute correctly?

Is there a possibility of executing this php script without adding the random string?

Comment: Are you sure you have to use php_cli? I think simply php will get the job done !

Comment: @Xander I am not sure about this but I it is not the cause of my problem too.